# how to calculate the volume by using the Cavalieri’s principle

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a solid ball of radius R. Cut a cylindrical hole, through the center of the ball, such that the remaining body has height h. Call this the donut D(R,h). Use Cavalieri’s principle to calculate the volume of D(R, h). Calculate the volumes of D(25, 6) and D(50, 6).

I am not really sure how to solve this question.
I thought i need to calculate (the volume of sphere)-(the volume of cylinder)

thank you for your help!!!

Comment: The intersection of a sphere and a cylinder is not a cylinder, so you need to can't just take the difference of the sphere and some cylinder. To answer the question, you might want to draw a picture first.

Comment: see the related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240138/volume-of-a-spherical-donut?rq=1